# Перескажите двумя словами что хотел сказать Дейтл, а то не врубаюсь

Tags: c++

Перескажите двумя словами что хотел сказать Дейтл, а то не врубаюсь:

> **Операции как элемент-функции и как глобальные функции**
>
> Независимо от того, объявляется ли функция-операция как 
>   элемент-функция или как глобальная функция, в выражении операция используется 
>   одинаковым образом. Так какой же вариант лучше?
>
> Когда функция-операция реализуется как элемент, левый (или 
>   единственный) операнд должен быть объектом (или ссылкой на объект), 
>   принадлежащим классу этой операции. Если необходимо, чтобы левый операнд был 
>   объектом другого класса или объектом основного типа, эта функция-операция
>   должна объявляться как функция, не являющаяся элементом класса (как мы
>   сделаем в разделе 11.5, где перегружаются « и » в качестве операций 
>   передачи и извлечения из потока). Глобальная функция-операция может быть 
>   сделана другом, если она должна иметь непосредственный доступ к закрытым
>   или защищенным элементам класса.
>
> Функции-операции, являющиеся элементами некоторого класса, 
>   вызываются (неявно компилятором) только когда левый операнд двухместной 
>   операции является объектом данного конкретного класса, либо когда единственный
>   операнд одноместной операции является объектом этого класса.

[image: скрин из книги]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы перегружаете оператор, скажем, + для класса X, его можно определить двумя способами - отдельной функцией

```
X operator+(const X& l, const X& r);
```

или как член класса X

```
X operator+(const X& r);
```

В первом случае, если класс X может быть создан из целого числа путем implicit conversion допустимы операции типа

```
1+x
```

где х - объект класса Х. Во втором случае объект класса всегда должен стоять на первом месте.